# WPF: Bindings not working correctly

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml, dependency-properties

Say I have XAML like

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TabTitle}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:UserControl1 Text="{Binding Text}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

I want to ask where does the `TabTitle` and `Text` properties come from? I think the should come from each item of `Tabs` right? Say Tabs is a `ObservableCollection<TabViewModel>` `TabTitle` & `Text` should be from `TabViewModel` properties right. But it seems true to a certain extend. `TabTitle` is populated correctly while `Text` is not.

`Text` is declared as a Dependency Property in `UserControl1` as follows

```
public string Text
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));
```

When I have tabs not bound to a `ObservableCollection<TabViewModel>` bindings works fine

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
    <TabItem Header="Tab 1">
        <local:UserControl1 Text="Hello" />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Tab 2">
        <local:UserControl1 Text="World" />
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: Check you output window for binding errors

Comment: Do you initialize TabViewModel.Text with some value? Or it is null? Also, does your TabViewModel implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are binging UserControl to the property from code-behind file, you should use

```
 {Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Text}
```

Direct binding as u have works only for DataContext

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what is the problem. The element in the UserControl1, which should be filled by Text property, doesn't observe the changes of this property. So there is two ways:

1) Use PropertyChangedCallback:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new UIPropertyMetadata(""),
    new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTextPropertyChanged));

private static void OnTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((UserControl1)sender).OnTextChanged();
}

private void OnTextChanged()
{
    this.myTextBlock.Text = this.Text;
}
```

2)Tricky binding:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl1" x:Name="root" ...>
...
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=root}"/>
...
</UserControl>
```

Comment: hmm... this still doesn't work, there isn't any errors tho. also i think the syntax for `DependencyProperty.Register` is `public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new UIPropertyMetadata("", new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTextChanged)));`

Comment: Put a breakpoint into TextChanged handler and check the value of property.